# Prolog backtracks and loses all values

Tags: prolog

I have a few prolog predicates which calculate the cost of given cities. The process begins with a command like: `best_route([std, lhr, bud, dse], 2013-5-5, X).`

```
best_route(Cities, StartDate, Cost):-
    begin_routing(Cities, StartDate, Cost, []).

begin_routing(Cities, StartDate, Cost, CostList):-
    route(Cities, StartDate, CostList),
    min_list(CostList, Cost).

route(Cities, StartDate, Costing):-
    % stop if all cities have been covered once.
    length(Cities, Stop),
    length(Costing, Stop);

    [Origin, Dest|_] = Cities,
    flights(Origin, Dest, StartDate, Costing, Cities, [Cities, Origin, StartDate]).
```

Using the trace function in SWI-Prolog, I found that once the route predicate - `length(Costing, Stop)` is satisfied i.e., length of Costing List is equal to Stop. Prolog instead of stopping there, and *proceeding* with `min_list(CostList, Cost)`, instead backtracks until CostLost loses all its values again. Once it finishes that, it goes to `min_list` when the list is `[]`.

I am not sure why this might be happening. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
flights(..):-
    % Code omitted.
    get_next_date(OriginalDate, NextDate),
    route(Cities, NextDate, [DayCost|Costing]).
    % where DayCost is a simple integer calculated before this is added to the current Costing list
```

Towards the end, the last correct call is `route([std, lhr, bud, dse], 2013-5-6, [329, 499, 323, 311]).`

Comment: Reading through `best_route` and `begin_routing`, it appears that when `route` is first called, `Cities` is instantiated to `[std, lhr, bud, dse]` and `Costing` is instantiated to `[]`. The call to `length(Costing, Stop)` becomes `length([], 4)` and fails. It is terminated in a disjunction (`;`) and, therefore `route` doesn't fail at that point but continues with `[Origin, Dest|_] = Cities` instantiating `Origin` and `Dest` and then calling `flights`. Since you don't show what `flights` does, it's unclear what it does from there.

Comment: @mbratch: Please have a look at the edited question, I am omitting parts of code as they are fairly unnecessary and lengthy. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @Namit:  min_list(CostList, Cost) fails or requires more evaluation ? to force termination, add a dumb alternative: ( min_list(CostList, Cost) ; true )

Comment: @mbratch: It fails because the `CostList` is not being carried over the recursion period. Adding `true` does not make much difference either.

Comment: @Namit, I was indicating why it didn't immediately go back to the `min_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the intention of `CostList` is to record the costs of different routes and then to select the one with the smallest cost. However, you initialize `CostList` as `[]`, and while the recursion is building `CostList` you do not provide means of communicating it back when the recursion returns. A possible solution would be to add a new argument `FinalCostList` that is being simply passed through the recursion until the termination clause. Alternatively, you can use difference lists.

To illustrate this point, consider the following example:

```
p :- q([]).
q(X) :- go(X), !, q([a|X]).
q(X) :- stop(X).
```

with some mutually exclusive `go` and `stop`. The desired outcome (`q` with all `a`s as long as `go`) is computed but not returned. A better solution would be

```
p(Y) :- q([],Y).
q(X,Y) :- go(X), !, q([a|X],Y).
q(X,X) :- stop(X).
```

As said above difference lists can also be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just to be clear are you saying that I should copy the contents of CostList to another argument which is carried through the recursion?

Comment: Essentially yes. You can also consider difference lists that combine passing information into recursion and out of it.